# No multiple definition error despite including source file in another and compiling both

Tags: c++, linker

Let's say I have 3 files:

Test.hh

```
#ifndef TEST_HH_
#define TEST_HH_

class Test
{
    int test() const;
};

#endif /* TEST_HH_ */
```

Test.cc:

```
#include "Test.hh"

int Test::test() const
{
    return 0;
}
```

main.cc:

```
#include "Test.cc"

int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

It does not compile (rather does not link), I understand why, I defined Test::test() in multiple translation units (in main.cc that includes Test.cc and in Test.cc):

```
g++ -Wall -g -std=c++17 -c main.cc -o main.o
g++ -Wall -g -std=c++17 -c Test.cc -o Test.o
g++ -o bin main.o Test.o
Test.o: In function `Test::test()':
Test.cc:12: multiple definition of `Test::test()'
main.o:Test.cc:12: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Edit: This is NOT my issue, my issue is that with a seemingly identical situation, in a bigger project, the previous example produces a binary (i.e. compiles and links) when, as far as I understand it, *it shouldn't*. I will now describe the real case with a bit more details and how the problem suddenly arised when previously it was working fine (when it *shouldn't have*).

--

I am currently working on a large project (~2500 files), and while trying to use the "Test" class above, I ended up having a lot of "multiple definitions" errors at link time. To translate it to our example, it's like I had another class doing this:

OtherClass.hh

```
#include "Test.hh" // including or using forward declaration led to the same results
//class Test; forward declaration

class OtherClass
{
    // Some stuff, whatever
};
```

I ended up finding that Test.cc was included in another source file (main.cc in my very simplified exemple though it was in another "someClass.cc" in my actual project). After including the header instead of the source, it compiled again. What's more surprising is that other classes had been using Test.hh the same way until then without any problems.

Since I was really surprised, I ended up doing a grep on all my files and found that another 2 source files had included other sources files as well.

WhateverClass.cc

```
#include "Test2.cc"
```

YetAnotherClass.cc

```
#include "Test3.cc"
```

All those files are compiled and contain function definitions yet the linker does not complain. I tried doing a compilation from scratch and it still worked.

So my question is: Why does this compile even though some source files include others and all of them are compiled ? And why did it suddenly stop working even though I just included the header of  one of those source files just like other classes had been doing ? Is there a kind of "undefined behavior" for cases like this ?

If it is of any help, my project is using CMake. I tried compiling with ninja or Make with the same results.

Comment: Why including source instead of header?

Comment: you should never `#include` source files

Comment: please include a [mcve] of the code your question is about. If I understand correctly you understand why your first example does not compile but the question is about different code that does compile

Comment: I think that all ODR violations which can be found only at linkage step doesn't require diagnostic.

Comment: "Test2.cc" and "Test3.cc" appear to be different files from "Test.cc" so that isn't a problem in and of itself. If you don't compile and link those two other files separately the linker will only see one definition.

Comment: I know that I should not include source files. It was probably a mistake that some source files were included at some point, maybe a bad copy/paste. But if such a mistake arises, I would hope that the code does not compile. But it did. And it suddenly stopped compiling later for an obscure reason. The minimal reproductible example is basically the one I described in my first example, only in my real project it compiles fine, and I don't understand why. As for Test2.cc and Test3.cc they are both compiled separately but WhateverClass.cc and YetAnotherClass.cc are also compiled with no error.

Comment: As I understand it, as soon as a source file includes another one and that they are both compiled, the linker should complain. But in my project it seems to be the case and it compiles fine, at least in some circumstances. That is what I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question before. So, here's what I learned- never include source file. Only include header files. Your error comes from including a source (`.cc`) file in your main. You should include `Test.hh` instead. Declare all your classes and functions in header, include that header to all the source files where the definitions and the calls are.

Comment: I know I should not include source files. My question is, when that happens by mistake, why is there the possibility (apparently) that the code will _still_ compile ?

Comment: Compilation means the translation of the code to machine language. If there is no syntax violation then any code will compile. But then the linking fails and give error in runtime.

Comment: By compiling I meant linking also, the final result is that the binary is built when it shouldn't.